# CSV file Read in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have two type of csv's  having data like:

Format 1 read from csv created from spreadsheet having two coloums.

```
datas = [[u'Woeoe;"ww@w.com"'], [u'wqqq;"Ww2@2.com"'], [u'Asasasa;"122@22.co.in"']]
```

format 2 read from the csv created from text editor save as .csv and having data like

```
fname lname,email@email.com
fname1 lname2 ,email@email1.com
datas = [[u'Vaada sasoe ', u'ssdoe@d.com'], [u'skdod asksd ', u'shashias@ssdsd.com']]
```

i have read those files with csv reader:

```
reader = csv.reader(input, quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
datas = []
for line in reader:
    datas.append(line)
```

how do i handle those two different format output of csv reader ? is their any way that i can convert the data while reading in to one simple comma separated format like format2 mention above if i input the any type of csv ? basically i want to data read should be in always in format2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first file use ";" as delimiter. So, you just have to say it to the reader.

Try to read the first file with `csv.reader(input, quotechar='"', delimiter=';')`

Comment: i tried this also but for spredsheet csv it give me out put like ['xod sdo','xod@gmail.com'] which is right but for the csv i created from text pad and save as csv it give me result like ['xod sdo,xod@gmail.com'] which should not happen .i am using the ubuntu environment.

Comment: @Shashi: Stop creating CSV's in text pad.  You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Because for the text from your text pad, you should use the first version of your reader which was correct. You should have one reader for the Excel and one another for the text file. Maybe you can say us more about the context in which you are doing this ? You have to stay with 1 universal reader ?

Comment: i created the csv file gedit type the data and save the file as .csv is it wrong process should i use only spreadsheet for that ?

Comment: if i able to identify the uploaded file so that i can use proper reader m i right ?

Comment: @Shashi: Stop creating CSV's in text pad. You're doing it wrong. It's not a "process".  It's "syntax".  When you try to create CSV with textpad, you don't create a proper CSV.  Actually look at your CSV.  Compare **every** character with CSV from the spreadsheet.  Yours is wrong.  You put the quotes are in the wrong places.  Don't do that.

Comment: If you have to user several format, yes, you should identify the file origin to make the right `reader` instance. Otherwise, the problem will disapear if you use only CSV generated from your spreadsheet as you say you finally will do.