# Python help ---> random name selection from text file

Tags: python, random, module, generator, names

I want to have a list of names such as "john, jack, daniels, whisky, susan, alex"  in a .txt file called 'names'.

Now, I want to import that file into my 'script' and use the import random module.

This is what I have:

```
import random

name = ( "jay" , "luis" , "bob" , "sofi", "susan" ) 

x = random.sample(name,input( "please enter the number of volunteers needed" ))
print x
```

instead of having `name = ( xxxxxxxxxxxxx )`, I want to have name = .txt file.

Everytime i want to change the names I can just change it in the .txt file.

I'm trying to make a program for my schools volunteer club, so the number of volunteers chosen is at random and not biased. That way everyone has a somewhat fair chance. :]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really need to google some basic python tutorials *(eg http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/fileio/ )* just open the file read it in and split the lines by ",". OR read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136154/csv-file-read-in-python

Answer (score 3):

```
file = open('myFile.txt', 'r')
names = file.read().split(',')
file.close()
```

Use that in place of your `name = ...` line and you should be good to go.

You can read more about reading and writing files in Python [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Note that I assumed you'll have a comma-delimited list in the file. You can also put each name on a separate line and do `names = file.readlines()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to python :-]

how about something like this?

```
import random
fid = open('names.txt', 'r')
names = fid.readlines()

number_needed = raw_input('please enter the number of volunteers needed: ')

print random.sample(names, int(number_needed))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply fill a text file with names delimited by line:

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    names = f.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a list of names in `names.txt`, one per line (and that you don't have a hundred million names in there):

```
import random
number_of_volunteers = 4
print random.sample([n[:-1] for n in open("./names.txt").readlines()], number_of_volunteers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where:

```
$ cat rand_nms.txt
jay
luis
bob
sofi
```

Then:

```
import random

contents=[]

with open("rand_nms.txt") as rnd:
    for line in rnd:
        line=line.strip()
        contents.append(line)

print contents
print "random name:", contents[random.randint(0,len(contents)-1)]
```

Result:

```
['jay', 'luis', 'bob', 'sofi', 'susan']
random name: luis
```